# How can I replace certain character when a user is typing on an input field?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6

I am trying to replace some characters on the fly but it is not working.
Look, I have this code which replaces any characters that are not URL friendly. I mean, the user will be typing on an input to construct a URL:

```js
function slugify(string) {
  const a =
    "àáâäæãåāăąçćčđďèéêëēėęěğǵḧîïíīįìłḿñńǹňôöòóœøōõőṕŕřßśšşșťțûüùúūǘůűųẃẍÿýžźż·/_,:;";
  const b =
    "aaaaaaaaaacccddeeeeeeeegghiiiiiilmnnnnoooooooooprrsssssttuuuuuuuuuwxyyzzz------";
  const p = new RegExp(a.split("").join("|"), "g");

  return string
    .toString()
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s+/g, "-") // Replace spaces with -
    .replace(p, (c) => b.charAt(a.indexOf(c))) // Replace special characters
    .replace(/&/g, "-and-") // Replace & with 'and'
    .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, "") // Remove all non-word characters
    .replace(/\-\-+/g, "-") // Replace multiple - with single -
    .replace(/^-+/, "") // Trim - from start of text
    .replace(/-+$/, ""); // Trim - from end of text
}
```

So for example when the user types a space, it should be replace with `-`, like here:

```
.replace(/\s+/g, "-") // Replace spaces with -
```

But that's not working. I noticed this one works:

```
.replace(/&/g, "-and-") // Replace & with 'and'
```

But why not the rest of them? Any ideas?

This is the whole code:

```
  const handleSiteUrl = (value) => {
    setNameToUrlAction({
      ...nameToUrl,
      siteUrl: slugify(value.toLowerCase()), // HERE I USE slugify METHOD
    });
  };

        <input
          id="siteUrl"
          name="siteUrl"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter name"
          value={`/${nameToUrl.siteUrl}`}
          onChange={(e) => handleSiteUrl(e.target.value)}
        />
```

Comment: @YannickK I posted in the question the scenario where the user types a space which should be replace with a hyphen, and that is not happening. So well the expected output is that when the user types in a space, I need a hyphen to be set instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.replace(/\s+/g, "-")
```

This replacement converts **space** to **hyphen(-)**

```
 .replace(/-+$/, "");
```

This replacement converts **hyphen(-)** back to **""**

So at the end you are getting **""** for every **space**